# showing errors while executing the project from git

Tags: android, import, telephony

hi i downloaded source code from [git](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Mms.git;a=summary).when i execute this code its showing errors at following lines of code.

```
    import android.provider.Telephony.Mms;
   import android.database.sqlite.SqliteWrapper;
```

its showing that

> "android.provider.Telephony.Mms" and
>   "android.database.sqlite.SqliteWrapper"

can't be resolved...pls tell me the reason..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on a tablet or non-phone device?

I'm not sure why the Sqlite import would be wrong, but a tablet with non-stock android might be lacking the entire `telephony` package.

Comment: i am running this application in emulator

Comment: Make sure you run on Google API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you need the entire AOSP source to build that app.

Those imports are not part of the public API as far as I know.

Comment: http://www.google.se/search?rlz=1C1DVCP_enSE436SE436&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=aosp

Comment: you are saying that ,need to download entire AOSP..what was wrong with my download...i downloaded mms from that link only

Comment: The mms app is part of the AOSP. It's not a standalone app, as far as I understand.

Comment: It says on the link I gave you how to do it. But you'll end up compiling the entire Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because these imports are unavailable in SDK version under which you're trying to compile project. Just select Android SDK 2.2 or SDK 2.3 and everything will be ok...

Comment: Thanks for your response. i am compiling under 2.2 version only.